# How to resize image in webworker using OffscreenCanvas given local url and return resized data to main thread?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blob, webgl, web-worker

I want to offload image loading and resizing from main thread. After reading about this, it seems that my options are combination of `fetch` `OffscreenCanvas` and `WebWorker`.

Thus far I got to following stage within my webworker code:

1. I pass `imageUrl` to web worker, that I then fetch, this gives me access to image data in it's blob format
2. I then create an offscreen canvas in order to prepare for image resizing (canvas seems to be most common method I found online)

Example code looks like this

```
const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
const blob = await response.blob();
const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas();
```

And I am stuck at this stage. All examples I found so far use `Image()` to create image from url and access its width / height values, as well as load data onto canvas.

In my case I only have access to blob and since we are in webworker I can't create `new Image()`, hence I'm not sure how to proceed further?

Ideally what would happen next is we load image blob onto canvas, resize it to say 50% and return either base64 of the image or BlobUrl to main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not looking into all browsers support I guess, you might consider using `createImageBitmap()` method, which takes among the others `Blob` data and returns `ImageBitmap`. Which could be used to read height and width of the fetched image and to draw it on the off-screen canvas as well.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap

Comment: I am still lost. The example in that link still uses Image which isn't available